# Removing objects from ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists.

```
List<MyObject> firstList (Size=5)
List<MyObject> secondList = firstList;
```

When I use this command

```
secondList.remove(0);
```

The object at 0 position in firstList is also getting deleted. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show full code please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only change the second line it will resolve your issue.

```
List<MyObject> firstList (Size=5)
List<MyObject> secondList = new ArrayList<>(firstList);


secondList.remove(0);
```

The issue is due to the  your line List secondList = firstList;

It will not create another object instead of  both the list point to the single object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your line `List<MyObject> secondList = firstList;`

This doesnt create another list, it just refers to the first list you created. You'll need to instantiate a separate list.

Answer (score 0):

Its correct because `secondList` have the reference of `firstList` so if you delete element form `secondList` its same as removing from `firstList`

use following code:

```
//create new arraylist which contains item of firstList list
List<MyObject> secondList = new ArrayList(firstList);
secondList.remove(0);//now it will only remove element from `secondList`
```